# How to Convert form inputs to json array and send it as http post request in body, using c# in mvc5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, post, http-post, webrequest

> This is what I want (json array):
>    [{"location":"uk","keyword":"developer","specialization":"asp.net","lat":"28.5654"},"long":78.3265"]`

This is what I tried to get json array:

```
var list = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();

        list.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Name", query.Name));
        list.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Specialization", query.Specialization));

        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(list);
```

> This is the result: [{"Key":"Name","Value":"Sam"},{"Key":"Specialization","Value":"ASP.Net"}]

**But I want it like this:**
[{"Name":"Sam","Specialization":"ASP.Net"}]

Comment: Can you provide us your controller? That would be helpful. Need to know if your controller action method taking in an array or an object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh right, so I think the solution is use a Dictionary instead KeyValuePair:

```
var list = new Dictionary<string,string>();

list.Add("location", mysearch.location);
list.Add("keyword", mysearch.keyword);
...

var listSerialized= JsonConvert.Serialize(list);
```

If you need an array you can do this:

```
var dictionaryList = new List<Dictionary<string, string>>();

foreach(search in mySearchList)
{
    var item = new Dictionary<string,string>();
    item.Add("location", search.location);
    item.Add("keyword", search.keyword);
    ...

    dictionaryList.Add(item);
}
var serializedArray = JsonConvert.Serialize(jsonArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm, I think you really need a list of key value pair instead an array, try this:

```
var list = new List<KeyValuePair<string,string>>();
list.Add(new KeyValuePair<string,string>("location": mysearch.location);
list.Add(new KeyValuePair<string,string>("keyword": mysearch.keyword);
...
```

You can use this as your body request, but if you need an array you can do:

```
var array = list.ToArray();
```

For help how to make an http post request, you can consult this post:
[How to make HTTP POST web request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4015324/how-to-make-http-post-web-request)

I hope be helpfull.